# box-sizing is not functioning properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to to create my own **custom** `select` tag, but stuck up with a strange issue.

Below is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="drop_select">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.drop_select {
    width:180px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(http://s22.postimg.org/liq7aghz5/select_icons.png) no-repeat 148px -165px #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.drop_select:hover {
    background-position: 148px -115px;
}
.drop_select select {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-background: transparent;
    -webkit-background: transparent;
    width: 202px;
    padding: 8px 5px 8px 8px;
    font: 12px arial;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    -o-background: #000000;
}
.drop_select:hover select {
    color: #ebb52d;
}
.drop_select select option {
    color: #fff;
    text-indent: 5px;
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 3px;
    width: 182px !important;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #515151;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.drop_select select option:hover, .drop_select select option:focus, .drop_select select option:active {
    background: #515151 !important;
    color: #dfb52d;
}
```

[image: Strange behavior]

> I'm using box-sizing and border-bottom working good in Firefox, but not in chrome and IE.  Above is the
> screenshot

Hope you can find the differences in the images above.  Also I've fiddled my code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6YU5x/1/), please provide you suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SebastianG No. Padding is not my problem, its about the box-sizing and border-line.  you can find the behavior difference in the pic.

Comment: However, you should describe what you mean by "working good". The firefox screenshot doesn't look correct for me, too.

Comment: @SebastianG In firefox, I am able to have a box-sized space with a dotted border.  whereas this is missing in chrome and IE10.

Comment: border-radius is not work in ie

Comment: @ankur IE9 and 10 will support border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you cannot style drop down options like that in Webkit browsers, currently. You could use a properly styled UL to achieve the same result though.